# How to add a class to Meteor useraccounts:semantic-ui?

Tags: javascript, meteor, semantic-ui, meteor-accounts

I am using `useraccounts:semantic-ui` and I would like to add a class of primary to the login/logout button.

This is the code that I am using:

```
<div class="item">{{> atNavButton }}</div>
```

That renders to the following:

```
<div class="item">
     <div class="ui button" id="at-nav-button">Sign Out</div>
</div>
```

What I want is the ability to add a class of primary so that it renders as `class="ui primary button"`?

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install [aldeed:template-extension](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-template-extension) in order to replace the template `atNavButton` with your custom template.

1. Run `meteor add aldeed:template-extension`.
2. Create your custom template:

---

```
<template name="atNavButtonCustom">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="ui primary button" id="at-nav-button">{{text}}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

---

3. Call the `replaces` function so that the template `atNavButtonCustom` will be rendered instead of `atNavButton`:

---

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.atNavButtonCustom.replaces("atNavButton");
}
```